# How to do a Hierarchical GroupBy?

Tags: gathering

Consider a simple `expr` as an example:

```
expr = {
    {a},{a,b},{a,c},{a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,f},
    {b,c},{b,d}
};
```

I want to `GroupBy` as much as possible keeping the hierarchy of `Keys` intact then apply a function `func` on the leaves.

> hierarchicalGroupBy[expr, func]

```
{
    a->{b->{c->{func[d],func[f]}},func[c]},
    b->{func[c],func[d]}
}
```

---

I forgot the case of a (long) branch with a single leaf (below is the updated example):

```
{
    {a},{a,b},{a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,f},{a,b,d,e},{a,b,e,d,c,f},{a,c},
    {b,c},{b,d},
    {c}
}
```

This should convert to:

```
{
    a->{b->{c->{func[d],func[f]},d->func[e],e->d->c->func[f]},func[c]},
    b->{func[c],func[d]},
    func[c]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proceed in two steps: first, recursive [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) with pruning at the leaves (`DeleteCases[{}]`) and generating lists-of-rules instead of associations ([`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html)):

```
hgb[A_] := Normal@GroupBy[A, First -> Rest, hgb@*DeleteCases[{}]]
```

Then, at the end apply the function `F` to the leaves, being careful to delay the application ([`:>`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)) just in case `F` needs it:

```
HierarchicalGroupBy[A_, F_] := hgb[A] /. (x_ -> {}) :> F[x]
```

Try it out:

```
expr = {{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, f}, {b, c}, {b, d}};
HierarchicalGroupBy[expr, func]

(*    {a -> {b -> {c -> {func[d], func[f]}}, func[c]},
       b -> {func[c], func[d]}}                           *)
```

To do the updated example, we can still use the above `GroupBy` recursion and redefine

```
HierarchicalGroupBy[A_, F_] := hgb[A] //. {(x_ -> {y_}) -> (x -> y),
                                           (x_ -> {}) :> F[x]}
```

so that

```
expr2 = {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, f}, {a, b, d, e},
         {a, b, e, d, c, f}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c}};
HierarchicalGroupBy[expr2, func]

(*    {a -> {b -> {c -> {func[d], func[f]}, d -> func[e], 
       e -> d -> c -> func[f]}, func[c]}, b -> {func[c], func[d]},
       func[c]}                                                       *)
```

Comment: Can you please try on the updated example if your solution works properly for a branch with a single leaf.

Comment: Here's my code in @kglr's one-line style as an anonymous recursion using the `#0` slot: `HierarchicalGroupBy = Normal@GroupBy[#,First->Rest,#0@*DeleteCases[{}]]&@#//.{(x_->{y_})->(x->y),(x_->{}):>#2@x}&`

Answer (score 6):

A variation on Roman's idea:

```
ClearAll[hG]
hG = Normal @ GroupBy[# /. {} -> Nothing , First -> Rest,  Function[x, hG[x, #2]]] /. 
     {Rule[a_, {b_}] :> Rule[a, b], Rule[a_, {}] :> #2[a]} &;

hG[expr, func]
```

> {a -> {b -> c -> {func[d], func[f]}, func[c]}, b -> {func[c], func[d]}}

```
hG[expr2, func]
```

> {a -> {b -> {c -> {func[d], func[f]}, d -> func[e], 
>            e -> d -> c -> func[f]}, func[c]}, b -> {func[c], func[d]}, 
>        func[c]}

Comment: Interesting use of a pure function with a free variable to avoid the need for an auxiliary function! If I understand correctly your modification didn't need `ReplaceRepeated` because you are making replacement at each step of the `GroupBy` recursion itself right?